# Prepaid cellphone (Handy) or SIM card for Germany, Czech Republic, Austria and Hungary?

Tags: germany, cellphones, austria, czech-republic, hungary

I'm going to spend all May 2014 in Germany, Czech Republic, Austria, and Hungry and I want to have a smart phone to have the possibility to see maps and thins kind of data and of course make some local calls.
So my question is what's the best way to solve this, buying in Berlin a phone, buying here in my country (Mexico) an unlocked phone and buy in Berlin a SIM card or maybe rent a phone in Berlin.
If someone has good advice or information I really appreciate it.

Comment: if you want to see maps, you can use/buy offline maps for your smartphone, it might end up cheaper than having a data plan (I suppose that's what you imply) or simply getting paper maps. Please clarify if you would like to make only calls or more.

Answer (score 2):

Get an unlocked phone at home - it will *probably* be cheaper, but more importantly easier to comparison shop and take your time to get familiar with the phone.

There are many providers of relatively cheap prepaid SIM cards in Germany, which all offer international roaming and due to EU regulations prices for this have become much more reasonable.

However, for more than minimal international data usage in a short time, ALDI Talk is the best provider I know of, since they have a package offering EU-wide data access for 5 EUR, valid for one week and recently upgraded to 120 MB:

http://www.alditalk.de/nord/Surfen/EU_Internet-Paket_120.php

But I'd still heed Vince's comment and get an offline map app, since intensive use of a map app can use up 120MB more quickly than you'd think.

Comment: I have very good maps in my iPad to navigate on off line, so this is covered, but anyway a very good advice!, but I would love to have access to the net to have info in specific places, like you normally have using a printed guide, so this time I will use just guides on line. On the other hand my trip start in Berlin but then I have a rented car so I would love to have the road help that google maps provide, and also have the possibility to make some local and international calls, mostly into Europe.

Comment: The ALDI talk may not be a good solution because they have no micro SIM cards. You must order them online, so first you loose time (if you're only a few days in Germany) and second, the issues with receiving post without 'external' address.

Answer (score 0):

A similar cheap prepaid SIM in Hungary could be [Bluemobile](http://www.bluemobile.hu/) in Lidl stores. You might try Tesco stores for their service or bigger service providers as Vodafone. Buying SIM cards in Hungary need registration of personal data, so a passport or ID must be at hand.

Comment: Actually, you can buy anonymous SIM cards at street kiosks of used phone dealers without any ID card.